# Unable to access Personal Certificate with web-service hosted in IIS 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-6, client-certificates

I am Unable to access Personal Certificate with web-service hosted in IIS 6.
But while running via VS 2013 its work fine.

With VS2013 I can access Personal Certificate with Store Name "My", but cannot fetch any data from IIS hosted site.

I have also turn AppPool 'Load User Profile' = true;

And not sure should I post this question, here or on 'Server Fault' section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Won't be able to Access Personal Certificate with web hosted in IIS.

To access any certificate from IIS hosted site:

First enable 'IIS Client Certificate Mapping Authentication' service from

```
[Windows feature] >> Internet Information Services >> World Wide Web Services >> Security
```

And import the certificate using MMC on any store i.e 'Web Hosting' but not 'Personal' Store.